# PHP when validating inputs in external file, how to prevent form from resetting the values

Tags: php, html

I have (simplifying), a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="file.php">
    <input name="test">
    <button>Send</button>
</form>

<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
        echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error'].'</p>';
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }
?>
```

and in **file.php**:

```
session_start();

$val = $_POST['test'];

if(!isset($val) || strlen($val) == 0 || empty($val)){
   $_SESSION['error'] = 'The "test" field cannot be empty."
}

header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
```

However, when I click send with an empty field the error shows up but the form is cleared. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: First of all, there's no point in using `isset()` and `empty()` at the same time. `empty()` does exactly the same as `isset()`, but also checks if there's a value inside. As for your question, there are several ways to solve it. You can use Ajax so the user doesn't actually browse away from the form, or you can sent the value of `$_POST['test']` back towards the form and load it into the input element.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the solutions below and if it doesn't work as I expect I'll do it with Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the test input to remain filled when you return? Try this:

Edit:

### File.php

Add a session to hold the entered input value.

```
$_SESSION['testValue']=$_POST["test"];
```

### Page1

On page load check if the session has a value, it it does, print it.

```
<input name="test" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION["testValue"]) ? $_SESSION["testValue"] : '';?>>
```

Comment: Almost but the page doesn't post back to itself. it posts to a 2nd processing file, that then sends a header to redirect back ot the other location.  afaik $_POST doesn't transfer with that...

Answer (score 1):

Add `$val` (or the whole `$_POST` as appropriate) to your `$_SESSION` and if if the session data is there on page1 you add the value in programatically

So **file.php** becomes

```
session_start();

$val = $_POST['test'];

if(!isset($val) || strlen($val) == 0 || empty($val)){
   $_SESSION['error'] = 'The "test" field cannot be empty.';
}
$_SESSION['priorPost']=$_POST; // note this change

header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
```

And **page1** becomes like this -

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
        echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error'].'</p>';
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="file.php">
    <input <?php if(isset($_SESSION['priorPost']['test'])){print("value='".$_SESSION['priorPost']['test']."'");} ?> name="test">
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Always check for the exact element with the `isset()` before trying to print it - elements that aren't filled out may not be in `$_POST` at all when the form was originally submitted.

You can do the same/similar for selected value(s) if you generate a select list, checkbox array, or radio button array programatically.